# About running multiple applications on the same port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two applications, can I run them on one port 8080? I am currently running them on different ports.

Comment: Yes, Sure with different context path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the equivalent of putting a proxy in-front of 2 apps anyway. You could deploy 2 different apps on a Servlet Container like Tomcat, but arguably you could consider Tomcat an app, but it's just perspective. The only reason you would want to do that is to share resources to minimize application runtime footprints, which nobody cares about anymore anyway.

Comment: So, I can’t run two applications on the same port?

Comment: If i use Tomcat

Comment: Yes, if you have 2 wars: `warA.war`, `warB.war`, there will be `/warA`, `/warB` paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tomcat then the answer is yes. When deploy, just choose the same Tomcat instance for both apps and voila. However it is advised to use multiple Tomcat instances and separate ports for different applications.